# SQL Query, get all ids that do not have a given status value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, datatable

I have a table called statuses shown below. Every time a user logs in a row is added. A status is added. I need to write a query that gives me all IDs one time that have never been 1, 6 or 8.

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

I wrote a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM statuses WHERE status NOT IN (1, 6, 8)
```

Unfortunately this gives me ID 2 and 3, but I don't want ID 2 to be selected because they have statuses 1, 6, and 8.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that a table in a relational database normally has a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by id and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id 
FROM statuses 
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(status IN (1, 6, 8)) = 0
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM statuses 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM statuses WHERE status IN (1, 6, 8))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2cd3e2cab4ba7ea9aba82c42e3ed8b22).